# Why does NetBeans give me Bad Value " " for attribute "action" when I try using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using Net Beans IDE 7.3.1.
The following code is flagged with the "Bad Value" in the title to my question:

```
<form name="profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
```

The error checker refers to white space in the URL under action.
The code does work, but I'd like to understand why Net Beans doesn't like it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Netbeans doesn't like it because thinks its HTML while its HTML combined with PHP.

Comment: Thanks Scony, Is there a way to get the correct coding warnings with this type of file?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea. Follow [this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195647). It seems to be bug.

Comment: Thanks again Scony, the discussion at the link was informative.